# Do MySQL actions on call - Node.js

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js, express

I have been learning some Node.js and was trying to make a program where you enter a username and password and it is checked against a MySQL database. I don't know if I'm doing the whole authentication business correctly, but my question is this: Can you call a MySQL function after the start of the code (i.e. on some kind of function call).

**Can you do a MySQL action on a function call?**

I've looked on the internet and different Stack Overflow questions, but I still don't really understand. I may be missing a trick about what Node.js actually does though.

This is my code:

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Basic User Information</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="http://localhost:8888/user" method="POST">
            Username: <input type="text" name="username"> <br>
            Password: <input type="text" name="password"> <br></select> 
            <input type="submit" value="submit">        
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Node.js:

```
//import the express module
var express = require('express');

//import body-parser
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

//store the express in a variable 
var app = express();

var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "password"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected!");
    con.query("CREATE DATABASE authtest", function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("Database created");
    });

    con.query("CREATE TABLE users (username VARCHAR(255), password VARCHAR(255))", function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("Table created");
    });
});

//configure body-parser for express
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//allow express to access our html (index.html) file
app.get('/index.html', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/" + "index.html");
});

//route the GET request to the specified path, "/user". 
//This sends the user information to the path  
app.post('/user', function(req, res){
    response = {
        username : req.body.username,
        password : req.body.password
    };

    //this line is optional and will print the response on the command prompt
    //It's useful so that we know what information is being transferred 
    //using the server
    console.log(response);

    //convert the response in JSON format
    res.end(JSON.stringify(response));

    con.connect(function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (response.username, response.password)";
        con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log("1 record inserted");
        });
    });
});

//This piece of code creates the server  
//and listens to the request at port 8888
//we are also generating a message once the 
//server is created
var server = app.listen(8888, function(){
    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port;
    console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port);
});
```

**Edit:**

Would I need to do this in another script? So, there is one for the initialisation of the page and one for inserting the data into the MySQL database?

Comment: Could you explain more about what you mean by “after the start of the code” or “MySQL action on a function call”? At least I don’t really understand what your problem in this is

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Near the bottom of the code, after `res.end(JSON.stringify(response));`, I am trying to insert the user's input from the input boxes into a MySQL database, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

as far i can see in your code you are setting a INSERT in the users table with the data passed by the form, and setting the server to respond before the action is complete so the page recieve the awnser anyway, but awnsering your question, YES, the actions you put in the "index.js" of your node server run as soon as it starts.